# Mercurial copy patch to repository

Tags: git, mercurial, repository

I'm using Mercurial repository and I have a patch in 'git' format and I wanted to know how I can apply that patch to my current repository which is Local.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`hg import <patchfile(s)>`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#import) should be able to handle git-style patches.

Use `hg import --no-commit <patchfile(s)>` if you don't want it to automatically commit the changes after each patch is imported.

Mozilla's FAQ mentions this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mercurial_FAQ#How_can_I_diff_and_patch_files.3f

Comment: It says from untrusted user, weird

Comment: You sure it's not talking about untrusted hooks?  That's the only trust model mercurial has built-into it, and it won't prevent the applying of patches.

Comment: I am fairly new to this but here is the error message 
patching file plugins/supported/text_editor/commands/editing.js
Hunk #1 FAILED at 129
1 out of 1 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file plugins/supported/text_editor/commands/editing.js.rej
abort: patch failed to apply

Answer (score 2):

Try `hg import --no-commit`, Mozilla has a [rather useful FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mercurial_FAQ) regarding trading patches between Git and Mercurial.

Depending on your platform, you can also just use `patch`, e.g. `patch -p1 < some_patch_from_git.patch`. That may actually be better as you'll see any fuzz and not have to deal with trusting the author just for one patch.

**Edit**

If your patch does not go in cleanly, none of the above methods are going to work. Your code base is not what the patch expects if hunks fail to apply. Look at the rejects and see what the patch expected your code to be at any given line, then rebase accordingly.

Comment: I think `hg import`ing a patch is better, as it will preserve the original committer’s name and timestamp.